# Calling an MVC Method USING $.ajax() and then on success call another method using $.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, get

the first thing you should know is that in the development environment works. :) But when the site is publish an exception is thrown. This is Crazy, i'm trying to call an mvc method using $.ajax function describe below. The method InsertProfileImage is called perfect, but when the  $.post function try to call the CreateUserAll method in mvc this exception is throw: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'CreateUserAll' was not found on controller.

Any ideas?

```
      var formData = new FormData();
                var file = $("#fuLoadImage")[0].files[0];
                formData.append("Image", file);
                formData.append("ImageName", $("#fuLoadImage")[0].files[0].name);
                formData.append("Command", (isNaN(parseInt(id)) ? "I" : "U").toString());



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/V_EMPLOYEE/InsertProfileImage",
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (ProfileID) {
                    if (ProfileID.ProfileID != -1 || ProfileID.ProfileID != null) {
                        params.PROFILEID = ProfileID.ProfileID;
                    }

                    $.post("/V_EMPLOYEE/CreateUserAll", params, function (success) {
                        if (success.success == false || success.success == null) {
                            alertify.alert("Error Inserting or Updating!");
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            // alertify.alert("Inserted/Updated Successfully!");
                            alertify.alert("Inserted/Updated Successfully!", function () {
                                window.location.href = "/V_EMPLOYEE/Index";
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alertify.alert(errorThrown.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: how is CreateUserAll defined in the Controller ?

Comment: That is a routing issue according to the error. Are you positive the routes are correct, and the method route is correct name? It is saying it cannot find it.

Comment: Te controller method name has to be wrongly routing. $.post and the $.ajax() are identical in the way you are using them. Can you post the code for the controller method as mentioned by user above?

Comment: you should be using the URL helper whenever possible.. You'd be surprised how many routing issues that solves.. `url: "@Url.Action("InsertProfileImage", "V_EMPLOYEE")"`   is `V_EMPLOYEE` your controller?  you have a controller named `V_EMPLOYEEController`?

Comment: [HttpPost]
     //   public JsonResult CreateUserAll(EmployeeViewModel formData, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
        public JsonResult CreateUserAll(EmployeeViewModel Data)
        {}

Comment: The question is why working properly in a production environment but when the site is published collapses ?, is something related to the routing?

Comment: Use fiddler to inspect on production, use RouteDebugger (on production or a semi production) too. careful as it could display to all users.